# Will OSGI equinox install copy jar to its own folder

Tags: osgi, equinox

I an curious of what installing a bundle into Equinox is supposed to do：

Will it actually copy my jar to somewhere inside Equinox folder so that when I delete my jar, it will not  affect the installed bundle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a bundle is installed (in any OSGi framework), it is persisted in the bundle cache. So yes, you can delete your JAR after installing it. The framework will remember what bundles were installed (and started) across restarts of the framework.

Comment: Assuming you don't use a reference: URL as supported by some OSGi framework implementations.

Comment: Which, as far as I know, is still not part of the OSGi specification, so you probably should not do that.

Comment: True. It is not part of the OSGi specification. But it is supported by the major implementations and people do use it.